# Is Master Program Rank Important for PhD Application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, united-kingdom, ranking

I am looking to go into the neuroscience or stem cell research fields. I was recently offered unconditional acceptance to the University of Edinburgh for Regenerative Medicine and to University College London for Neuroscience. Both are one year masters programs and included a dissertation.

Essentially, I am wondering how rank plays a role in applying to PhD programs. Does rank play a part in doctoral  acceptances? Both are well ranked, but UCL is ten or so spots higher on a world ranking scale.

Most of the research I have done has said that rank can be important for jobs, but I have not found much regarding the transition into a PhD, which I plan on.

I appreciate any input or opinions on the matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's so important for terminal masters degree, although it should not be completely disregarded. What is much more important, in my opinion, is the exact field you are intending to work in and the person you will work with and the references that you will get in the end (and, again, who they come from).

So if Edinburgh would give you the chance to work with a leading scholar in a subfield you are interested in, and UCL is ranked 10 ranks higher *generally*, but not *as compelling* for your more specific interest, I would go with Edinburgh.

Also, 10 is really not much of a difference.